# Getting constraints to work in size classes

Tags: ios, xcode

So, I'm playing around with size classes in Xcode 6 beta. I set up some constraints on an image such that it is in a different position based on size classes corresponding to iPhone portrait and landscape.

The constraints are visible in the images below. As you can see, when I am in Compact/Compact, some constraints are "installed" while others are not, and in Compact/Regular, other constraints are installed.

[image: Compact/Compact]
[image: Compact/Regular]

However, I get an error (slightly visible in both screenshots) basically claiming that my uninstalled constraints are interfering with my installed constraints (which, if they were run at the same time, is true) but shouldn't the uninstalled constraints for each size class not even be run? None of the installed constraints cause issues with each other.

The error that shows up is:

```
2014-06-30 21:14:26.215 TV Tracker[26417:1434692] SetAppThreadPriority: setpriority failed with error 45
2014-06-30 21:14:26.372 TV Tracker[26417:1434692] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb11da0 H:|-(24)-[UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...']   (Names: '|':UIControl:0x10bb2db60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb11df0 H:[UIImageView:0x10bb44740]-(>=18)-[UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb2f420 H:|-(20)-[UIButton:0x10bb35470'Sign In']   (Names: '|':UIControl:0x10bb2db60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb2f470 UIButton:0x10bb35470'Sign In'.leading == UIImageView:0x10bb44740.leading>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb11df0 H:[UIImageView:0x10bb44740]-(>=18)-[UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...']>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-30 21:14:26.373 TV Tracker[26417:1434692] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb11e90 H:[UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...']-(23)-|   (Names: '|':UIControl:0x10bb2db60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb11ee0 UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...'.trailing == UIButton:0x10bb44ec0'Register'.trailing>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb2f510 H:[UIButton:0x10bb44ec0'Register']-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UIControl:0x10bb2db60 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb11ee0 UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...'.trailing == UIButton:0x10bb44ec0'Register'.trailing>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-30 21:14:26.388 TV Tracker[26417:1434692] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb49e10 h=-&- v=-&- UIControl:0x10bb2db60.width == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x10d102000.width>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb55d10 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x10d102000.width == UINavigationTransitionView:0x10bc6f770.width>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb3cda0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x10bc6f770.width == UILayoutContainerView:0x10bc6e3e0.width>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb29960 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x10bc6e3e0.width == UITransitionView:0x10bc73670.width>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb559e0 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0x10bc73670.width == UIWindow:0x10d068e70.width>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb56880 h=--- v=--- H:[UIWindow:0x10d068e70(320)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb2f420 H:|-(20)-[UIButton:0x10bb35470'Sign In']   (Names: '|':UIControl:0x10bb2db60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb2f470 UIButton:0x10bb35470'Sign In'.leading == UIImageView:0x10bb44740.leading>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb44570 UIControl:0x10bb2db60.centerX == UIImageView:0x10bb44740.centerX>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb3c840 H:[UIImageView:0x10bb44740(92)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb3c840 H:[UIImageView:0x10bb44740(92)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-30 21:14:26.389 TV Tracker[26417:1434692] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x10bd1c8a0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x10bb4acb0(64)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x10bd1fbf0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x10bb4acb0]   (Names: '|':UIControl:0x10bb2db60 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb56d40 h=-&- v=-&- UIControl:0x10bb2db60.height == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x10d102000.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb56c60 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x10d102000.height == UINavigationTransitionView:0x10bc6f770.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb3cbb0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x10bc6f770.height == UILayoutContainerView:0x10bc6e3e0.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb4a920 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x10bc6e3e0.height == UITransitionView:0x10bc73670.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb0e3a0 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0x10bc73670.height == UIWindow:0x10d068e70.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb44d20 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0x10d068e70(568)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb44520 UIControl:0x10bb2db60.centerY == UIImageView:0x10bb44740.centerY>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb445c0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x10bb4acb0]-(24)-[UIImageView:0x10bb44740]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb49b60 V:[UIImageView:0x10bb44740(100)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb49b60 V:[UIImageView:0x10bb44740(100)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-30 21:14:26.396 TV Tracker[26417:1434692] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x10bd13470 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x10bb4c690(0)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x10bd13410 _UILayoutGuide:0x10bb4c690.bottom == UIControl:0x10bb2db60.bottom>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb56d40 h=-&- v=-&- UIControl:0x10bb2db60.height == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x10d102000.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb56c60 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x10d102000.height == UINavigationTransitionView:0x10bc6f770.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb3cbb0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x10bc6f770.height == UILayoutContainerView:0x10bc6e3e0.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb4a920 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x10bc6e3e0.height == UITransitionView:0x10bc73670.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb0e3a0 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0x10bc73670.height == UIWindow:0x10d068e70.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10bb44d20 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0x10d068e70(568)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb11e40 UIControl:0x10bb2db60.centerY == UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...'.centerY + 0.25>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb2f3d0 V:[UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...']-(91)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x10bb4c690]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10bb2d790 V:[UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...'(69)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

My sidebar for the Compact/Compact constraints look like
[image: C/C sidebar]

My sidebar for the Compact/Regular constraints look like
[image: C/R sidebar]

My view hierarchy for this login controller:
[image: view hierarchy]

Comment: You need to copy the **text** of the error message and paste it into your question.

Comment: Your screen shot shows the wrong thing. There is an "installed" checkbox. You need to generate and set multiple "installed" checkboxes for different size class states. Show _that_ screen shot, to prove that you are doing this correctly. Otherwise, you are just removing and adding actual constraints, not conditionally based on the size class. You must correctly cover every case: the general case and any specific size class states you are interested in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem the first time I tried this feature, until I realized what the "+" buttons were telling me. At first, I had changed size class and deleted a view and added a view, or deleted a constraint and added a constraint. That is wrong! You cannot delete or add views or constraints on a per-size-class basis; they must *all* be there in every size class — only some of them are marked "installed" for that size class, and others are not.

Here's some further advice.

- Look at the top of your screen shot. You are getting warnings from Interface Builder - and ignoring them. Don't ignore them! Those warnings are telling you that your constraints are not doing what you think they are.
- Show the view hierarchy list at the left of the canvas (it is hidden in your screen shots) and keep looking at and working on every combination of size class until there are *no more warnings*. It also tells you what constraints and views are present in the mass case and for the particular size class case you are looking at (see screen shot below).
- Use the "+" buttons in the attributes inspector on the right to make certain that you have values for every relevant size class case. You do not add or remove constraints or classes: you add "installed" buttons and mark their size class and check or uncheck them (again, see screen shot).

[image]

Finally, use the Preview Assistant to make certain the view will look the way you expect. See cute animation below.

[image]

Comment: The warnings are (I think) unrelated - I have a "Prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers" and a "Ambiguous Layout: Scrollable content size is ambiguous for "Table View"." warning for another view.

Comment: Ambiguous layout is ambiguous layout. It's bad.

Comment: Additionally, preview assistant looks fine for the view in landscape and portrait.

Comment: Agreed, ambiguous layout is bad... the project isn't quite complete and I was going to address that view later. I can fix those and see if that helps.

Additionally, the view I'm currently working on only is expected to appear in C/C and C/R size classes, so I don't have any constraints (or for that matter, any subviews) in the other size classes

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Perhaps there has to be a base case ("Any/Any")?

Comment: Well. That appears to have done it. Cheers!

If you update the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I can't take credit for that. I _thought_ it but I wasn't sure of it. I'm glad I nudged you in the right direction, though! Really, you should answer your own question and, in a couple of days, you can even accept your own answer. Well done! I'll leave my answer there in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you can notice first warning from your log
-(24)-[UILabel:0x10bb4db70'TV Tracker uses your Trak...']
Its clearly says that there is a constraint which is added by you is not required.
Take a example like this, If you added the top space and bottom space for any of the object you no need to set the height for that object because that object will expand based on the top and bottom spaces provided by you. 
Like the same way your log also says that UILable don't require the height/width/x/y which is equal to 24. Please find it and remove from storyboard that will resolve your issue.